# PHP Getting data from a url that redirects

Tags: php

I am trying to load data from a site that returns XML, but it only returns the XML once it does a redirect for security purposes. How do I configure a PHP request that will follow this redirect and receive the output?

Comment: use `curl` and it's options

Comment: Curl is the only option? I don't have complete access to the server using PHP and can't add anything new. It is my understanding that curl is not default in php and needs to be installed.

Comment: Is file_get_contents() enabled on the server? That should follow redirects and return the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) should follow HTTP redirects. According to the default [HTTP context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) `follow_location` is enabled and `max_redirects` is 20.

In this example `$xml` should contain the XML of wherever the original page redirects to:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

If that doesn't work you can verify that the default context options aren't being overridden by specifying a custom context:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array (
        'http' => array (
            'follow_location' => true,
            'max_redirects' => 20
        )
    )
);
$xml = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had assumed that this would not work since simplexml_load_file did not. I should try other things before I perform assumptions. The same answer was given by Levi.

Comment: I tried the same code you mentioned but it not working with redirects :(